# How does a CentOS 7 install verifies integrity?

Tags: centos, hashsum

How can the media (DVD) contain the hash if the hash is about the DVD? :)

Before installing a CentOS 7, it usually wants to check the "media" integrity.

Or is it using many smaller hashes to check given files?

Comment: What do you mean? Why would the fact that the medium contains the hash file be a problem?

Answer (score 0):

I think you're confusing something here.  You can calculate a hash of the whole ISO image, and it's a fine idea to verify that before installing the ISO image. If it's a true [cryptographic hash](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cryptographic_hash_function), I *think* you're right that there wouldn't be a way to embed the ISO's own hash inside the ISO.

But for all the files contained *inside* the iso, it is no problem, when preparing the iso, to calculate their hashes and add that list of hashes inside the iso, alongside the files. I don't know precisely what the integrity check does, but it would make complete sense for it to verify the hashes of the files it contains. If you have already verified the ISO's hash, this step wouldn't be necessary, but the installer doesn't know that you've already done that.